# Dual boot w/ windows 7

Tags: boot, 12.10

So my PC had windows XP and Win 7 on it and I went into the XP partition and installed Ubuntu 12.10 over it being sure to use 90% of the XP partition for the / mount and 10% for the swap. It installed but when I boot the computer it doesn't give me the option of choosing between 7 or Ubuntu, just booting right to the Linux distro. Should I have installed it in 7 over the XP partition? I can see the drive in Ubuntu that contains all the 7 files. How can I recover my 7 access?

Comment: try pressing and holding Shift key during bootup. It forces Grub to display its menu if it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sudo update-grub" in a terminal. This should tell the bootloader to look for your Windows 7 partition and allow you to switch next time you boot up.